# Animating Wheel of Fortune style view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm implementing a Wheel of Fortune-style SwiftUI view. It takes an array of Players and shows a wheel with slices representing each player.

I can show slices and labels correctly but struggle with the animation part of the view—specifically, animating labels to stick with their corresponding slice shape.

This is the current state of my implementation. As you can see even though I'm animating labels to the correct end position, they're not sticking with their slice and animate independently.

[image]

I am looking to update my below code to achieve a more realistic animation.

**This is the main WheelView that creates slices and labels and handles animation**

```
struct WheelView: View {
    let players: [Player]
    let colors = (0...10).map { _ in Color.random() }
    @State var rotation = 0.0
    
    private var anglePerSlice: Double {
        360.0 / Double(players.count)
    }
    
    func offsetDegree(index: Int) -> Double{
        (Double(index) * anglePerSlice + anglePerSlice / 2 + rotation).degreesToRadians
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                ForEach(Array(zip(players.indices, players)), id: \.0) { index, player in
                    SliceView(player: player,
                              index: index,
                              angle: anglePerSlice,
                              rotation: rotation)
                    .fill(colors[index])
                    .overlay(
                        ZStack {
                            SliceBorder(index: index,
                                        angle: anglePerSlice)
                            .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 3)
                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotation))
                        
                            Text(player.name)
                                .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(index) * anglePerSlice + anglePerSlice / 2 + rotation))
                                .offset(x: cos(offsetDegree(index: index)) * 150 ,
                                        y: sin(offsetDegree(index: index)) * 150)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                let randomAmount = Double(Int.random(in: 700..<1500))
                rotation += randomAmount
            }
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.5), value: rotation)
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

**This is SliceView which is a simple Shape that draws an arc**

```
struct SliceView: Shape {
    var player: Player
    var index: Int
    var angle: Double
    var rotation: Double
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        let startAngle = Double(index) * angle
        let endAngle = angle + Double(index) * angle
        var path = Path()

        path.move(to: center)
        path.addArc(center: center,
                    radius: rect.width / 2,
                    startAngle: .degrees(startAngle),
                    endAngle: .degrees(endAngle),
                    clockwise: false)
        
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path.rotation(.degrees(rotation)).path(in: rect)
    }
    
    var animatableData: Double {
        get { return rotation }
        set { rotation = newValue }
    }
}
```

**And couple of helpers**

```
struct SliceBorder: Shape {
    var index: Int
    var angle: Double
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        let startAngle = Double(index) * angle
        let endAngle = angle + Double(index) * angle
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: center)
        path.addArc(center: center,
                    radius: rect.width / 2,
                    startAngle: .degrees(startAngle),
                    endAngle: .degrees(endAngle),
                    clockwise: false)
        
        path.closeSubpath()

        return path
    }
}

extension Double {
    var degreesToRadians: Double { return Double(self) * .pi / 180 }
}
```

SwiftUI somehow decides to animate the label's `offset` smoothly from `rotation`'s start to end value. In reality, for `offset`, I want `rotation`'s value to increase one by one so that `offset` can have a circular animation effect.

Any suggestions on how can I achieve this?

Comment: Perfect use case for `Animatable`, I think that way you can get progress to update the `Text`

Comment: I agree. The docs for `Animatable` are here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/animatable. You could also take a look at `Lottie`: https://designcode.io/swiftui-handbook-lottie-animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to apply `rotation` to the wheel as a whole, rather to the individual subviews. Here's a simpler implementation of a fortune wheel, that works as you need:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var rotation: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Wheel(rotation: $rotation)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .rotationEffect(.radians(rotation))
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.5), value: rotation)
            Button("Spin") {
                let randomAmount = Double(Int.random(in: 7..<15))
                rotation += randomAmount
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct Wheel: View {
    
    @Binding var rotation: CGFloat
    
    let segments = ["Steve", "John", "Bill", "Dave", "Alan"]
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack {
                ForEach(segments.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .inset(by: proxy.size.width / 4)
                            .trim(from: CGFloat(index) * segmentSize, to: CGFloat(index + 1) * segmentSize)
                            .stroke(Color.all[index], style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: proxy.size.width / 2))
                            .rotationEffect(.radians(.pi * segmentSize))
                            .opacity(0.3)
                        label(text: segments[index], index: CGFloat(index), offset: proxy.size.width / 4)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    var segmentSize: CGFloat {
        1 / CGFloat(segments.count)
    }
    
    func rotation(index: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        (.pi * (2 * segmentSize * (CGFloat(index + 1))))
    }
    
    func label(text: String, index: CGFloat, offset: CGFloat) -> some View {
        Text(text)
            .rotationEffect(.radians(rotation(index: CGFloat(index))))
            .offset(x: cos(rotation(index: index)) * offset, y: sin(rotation(index: index)) * offset)
    }
}

extension Color {
    
    static var all: [Color] {
        [Color.yellow, .green, .pink, .cyan, .mint, .orange, .teal, .indigo]
    }
}
```

[image]